# $nearSphere returns too many data. What am I missing? Am I wrong? Is it a bug? Does other see the same thing?

Tags: mongodb, spatial

I noticed that $near and $nearSphere returns completely different data and I got suspicious. After all, when latitude is near equator it sphere distance shouldn't differ a lot from euclidean distance.

```
db.tablebusiness.find({ "LongitudeLatitude" : { "$nearSphere" : [106.772835, -6.186753], "$maxDistance" : 0.053980478460939611 }, "Prominent" : { "$gte" : 15 }, "indexContents" : { "$all" : [/^soto/, /^nasi/] } }).limit(200);
```

It returns 48 data.

I'll attached it anyway

```
/* 0 */
{
  "_id" : "nasi-uduk-soto-ayam__-6.18_106.77",
  "BuildingID" : null,
  "Title" : "Nasi Uduk Soto Ayam",
  "InBuildingAddress" : null,
  "Building" : null,
  "Street" : "Jl. Panjang",
  "Districts" : [],
  "City" : "Jakarta",
  "Country" : "Indonesia",
  "LongitudeLatitudeFromGoogle" : null,
  "DistanceFromGoogleAddress" : 0.0,
  "Checkin" : 0,
  "Note" : null,
  "PeopleCount" : 0,
  "Prominent" : 45.5,
  "CountViews" : 0,
  "StreetAdditional" : null,
  "LongitudeLatitude" : {
    "Longitude" : 106.765673160553,
    "Latitude" : -6.17522230915668
  },
  "Rating" : {
    "Stars" : 0.0,
    "Weight" : 0.0
  },
  "CurrentlyWorkedURL" : null,
  "Reviews" : [],
  "ZIP" : null,
  "Tags" : ["Restaurant"],
  "Phones" : [],
  "Website" : null,
  "Email" : null,
  "Price" : null,
  "openingHour" : null,
  "Promotions" : [],
  "SomethingWrong" : false,
  "BizMenus" : [],
  "Brochures" : [],
  "Aliases" : [],
  "indexContents" : ["restaura", "estauran", "staurant", "taurant", "aurant", "urant", "rant", "ant", "nt", "t", "nasi", "asi", "si", "i", "uduk", "duk", "uk", "k", "soto", "oto", "to", "o", "ayam", "yam", "am", "m"]
}

/* 1 */
{
  "_id" : "nasi-soto-padang_pasar-slipi-jaya_-6.19_106.80",
  "BuildingID" : null,
  "Title" : "Nasi Soto Padang",
  "InBuildingAddress" : "Lt.1 Los Alas",
  "Building" : null,
  "Street" : "Jl.Kemanggisan Utama Raya",
  "Districts" : [],
  "City" : "Jakarta",
  "Country" : "Indonesia",
  "LongitudeLatitudeFromGoogle" : null,
  "DistanceFromGoogleAddress" : 0.0,
  "Checkin" : 0,
  "Note" : null,
  "PeopleCount" : 0,
  "Prominent" : 45.5,
  "CountViews" : 0,
  "StreetAdditional" : null,
  "LongitudeLatitude" : {
    "Longitude" : 106.79647564888,
    "Latitude" : -6.18998465381734
  },
  "Rating" : {
    "Stars" : 0.0,
    "Weight" : 0.0
  },
  "CurrentlyWorkedURL" : null,
  "Reviews" : [],
  "ZIP" : null,
  "Tags" : ["Restaurant"],
  "Phones" : [],
  "Website" : null,
  "Email" : null,
  "Price" : null,
  "openingHour" : null,
  "Promotions" : [],
  "SomethingWrong" : false,
  "BizMenus" : [],
  "Brochures" : [],
  "Aliases" : [],
  "indexContents" : ["restaura", "estauran", "staurant", "taurant", "aurant", "urant", "rant", "ant", "nt", "t", "nasi", "asi", "si", "i", "soto", "oto", "to", "o", "padang", "adang", "dang", "ang", "ng", "g"]
}
```

...

```
/* 47 */
{
  "_id" : "nasi-gandul__-7.43_109.24",
  "BuildingID" : null,
  "Title" : "Nasi Gandul",
  "InBuildingAddress" : null,
  "Building" : null,
  "Street" : "Jl. Brobahan Pr - 40 rt 004 Rw 004",
  "Districts" : [],
  "City" : "Purwokerto",
  "Country" : "Indonesia",
  "LongitudeLatitudeFromGoogle" : null,
  "DistanceFromGoogleAddress" : 0.0,
  "Checkin" : 0,
  "Note" : null,
  "PeopleCount" : 0,
  "Prominent" : 30.5,
  "CountViews" : 0,
  "StreetAdditional" : null,
  "LongitudeLatitude" : {
    "Longitude" : 109.239182174206,
    "Latitude" : -7.42585664273589
  },
  "Rating" : {
    "Stars" : 3.0,
    "Weight" : 1.0
  },
  "CurrentlyWorkedURL" : null,
  "Reviews" : [],
  "ZIP" : "53116",
  "Tags" : ["Angkringan", "Restaurant Indonesian", "Soto & Sop"],
  "Phones" : ["+62(281)7918181"],
  "Website" : null,
  "Email" : null,
  "Price" : null,
  "openingHour" : null,
  "Promotions" : [],
  "SomethingWrong" : false,
  "BizMenus" : [],
  "Brochures" : [],
  "Aliases" : [],
  "indexContents" : ["angkring", "ngkringa", "gkringan", "kringan", "ringan", "ingan", "ngan", "gan", "an", "n", "restaura", "estauran", "staurant", "taurant", "aurant", "urant", "rant", "ant", "nt", "t", "indonesi", "ndonesia", "donesian", "onesian", "nesian", "esian", "sian", "ian", "soto", "oto", "to", "o", "&", "sop", "op", "p", "nasi", "asi", "si", "i", "gandul", "andul", "ndul", "dul", "ul", "l"]
}
```

I put the data into excel and compute the distance using this formula

=SQRT(POWER(E2-$G$1,2)+POWER((F2-$H$1)*COS($H$1*PI()/180),2))

That one should greatly approximate spherical distance. Also notice that latitude is -6 which is not far from equator.

Here is the result

```
0.013516826
0.023857967
0.037658667
0.038737146
0.042414787
0.046725248
0.051006427
0.053567221
0.057448344
0.061592999
0.062329244
0.065276161
0.066035611
0.076251787
0.109671831
0.112097201
0.13417281
0.136471939
0.172293693
1.058802838
1.078123028
1.079160684
1.080954023
1.081148114
1.081099449
1.092061283
1.094281476
1.094431917
1.096845722
1.097063729
1.096953691
1.097201996
1.105389179
1.105442127
1.10839237
1.108717834
1.108840349
1.111636423
1.113187903
1.118767984
1.118767984
1.133952371
1.135077548
1.154967917
1.161142923
1.185994885
1.199509086
2.756884824
```

Here is the screenshot of my excel sheet[image]

Here is the actual excel

```
            106.772835  -6.186753
  "_id"      "nasi-uduk-soto-ayam__-6.18_106.77",   106.7656732 -6.175222309    0.013516826
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-padang_pasar-slipi-jaya_-6.19_106.80",  106.7964756 -6.189984654    0.023857967
  "_id"      "nasi-uduk-soto-ayam__-6.22_106.77",   106.7718959 -6.224620499    0.037658667
  "_id"      "nasi-campur-%26-soto-babat-kenanga_komp.-ruko-permata-senayan%2C_-6.22_106.79",   106.79199   -6.22062    0.038737146
  "_id"      "soto-mie-nasi_indomaret-(univ.-mercu-buana)_-6.21_106.74",    106.7379928 -6.211082144    0.042414787
  "_id"      "soto-kudus%2C-soto-ayam-%26amp%3B-nasi-pindang_plaza-senayan_-6.23_106.80",   106.7989969 -6.225694167    0.046725248
  "_id"      "soto-kudus%2C-soto-ayam-%26amp%3B-nasi-pindang_plaza-bri-ii_-6.22_106.81",    106.8136847 -6.217476287    0.051006427
  "_id"      "soto-kudus%2C-soto-ayam-%26amp%3B-nasi-pindang_automall-indonesia_-6.23_106.81",  106.8096431 -6.225898946    0.053567221
  "_id"      "soto-kudus%2C-soto-ayam-%26amp%3B-nasi-pindang_menara-mulia_-6.22_106.82",    106.81656   -6.224232983    0.057448344
  "_id"      "nasi-gule-gandaria__-6.24_106.80",    106.795285  -6.244444863    0.061592999
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-monggo-mampir__-6.24_106.80",   106.7971516 -6.244479441    0.062329244
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam-\"pak-min\"__-6.24_106.82",    106.8151546 -6.236743573    0.065276161
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam-pak-min---santa__-6.24_106.81",    106.812959  -6.239508   0.066035611
  "_id"      "soto-mie-nasi-bogor__-6.23_106.83",   106.8322349 -6.234845139    0.076251787
  "_id"      "nasi-uduk-soto-ayam__-6.24_106.87",   106.8693781 -6.239089942    0.109671831
  "_id"      "soto-ayam-%2F-nasi-uduk-betawi__-6.28_106.71",    106.714092  -6.282785   0.112097201
  "_id"      "soto-minang-roda-jaya_ruko-tongkol-indah_-6.12_106.89",   106.889044  -6.119294471    0.13417281
  "_id"      "nasi-bebek-dan-soto-mas-muchlis_summarecon-kelapa-gading_-6.16_106.91",   106.9059021 -6.156281135    0.136471939
  "_id"      "nasi-liwet-%26-soto-kwali-kalimalang__-6.25_106.93",  106.9338112 -6.248527508    0.172293693
  "_id"      "soto-ayam-nasi-rames__-6.88_107.58",  107.5751638 -6.881692483    1.058802838
  "_id"      "nasi-liwet-soto-solo_rumah-mode_-6.88_107.60",    107.5998616 -6.882452292    1.078123028
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam-madura__-6.91_107.57", 107.5749707 -6.912900474    1.079160684
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-mie__-6.89_107.60", 107.5969434 -6.890355658    1.080954023
  "_id"      "nasi-rames-soto-bandung-enjoi__-6.89_107.60", 107.5970721 -6.890504777    1.081148114
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam__-6.91_107.58",    107.5769877 -6.913560825    1.081099449
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam__-6.91_107.60",    107.5977552 -6.90656    1.092061283
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam-madura__-6.89_107.62", 107.6157832 -6.888615935    1.094281476
  "_id"      "nasi-goreng-soto-ayam__-6.90_107.61", 107.6093245 -6.89662571 1.094431917
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-gulai-kambing__-6.90_107.61",   107.6090455 -6.900715755    1.096845722
  "_id"      "putra-bengawan-nasi-goreng-%26-soto__-6.89_107.62",   107.617187  -6.891298   1.097063729
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam__-6.90_107.61",    107.6088095 -6.901163102    1.096953691
  "_id"      "nasi-uduk-%26amp%3B-soto-kikil-cak-khohar__-6.89_107.61", 107.6144958 -6.894765295    1.097201996
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam__-6.90_107.62",    107.6204395 -6.900453028    1.105389179
  "_id"      "nasi-goreng-soto-ayam__-6.90_107.62", 107.6206326 -6.900303912    1.105442127
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam-madura__-6.91_107.62", 107.6169634 -6.909279174    1.10839237
  "_id"      "nasi-soto_pasar-baru_-6.92_107.61",   107.605226  -6.923423387    1.108717834
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam-madura_pasar-baru_-6.92_107.61",   107.6053333 -6.92348729 1.108840349
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-sarinah__-6.90_107.63", 107.631175  -6.897282   1.111636423
  "_id"      "nasi-uduk-soto__-6.89_107.64",    107.6361465 -6.893636262    1.113187903
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam-madura__-6.91_107.63", 107.629376  -6.910677   1.118767984
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam__-6.91_107.63",    107.629376  -6.910677   1.118767984
  "_id"      "nasi-uduk-soto__-6.94_107.62",    107.6248813 -6.93937772 1.133952371
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam-khas-madura__-6.94_107.63",    107.625749  -6.940099   1.135077548
  "_id"      "nasi-uduk-%26amp%3B-soto__-6.96_107.64",  107.638936  -6.955310213    1.154967917
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam_ruko-metro-trade-center_-6.94_107.66", 107.6600504 -6.940208438    1.161142923
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam-khas-madura__-6.94_107.69",    107.6948118 -6.937141164    1.185994885
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam-khas-madura-cak-nonk__-6.93_107.72",   107.7156472 -6.932668019    1.199509086
  "_id"      "nasi-gandul__-7.43_109.24",   109.2391822 -7.425856643    2.756884824
```

Look again the term in the query

```
"$maxDistance" : 0.053980478460939611
```

Go figure.

Comment: Can you please clarify what your question is here?

Comment: updated the question title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing too many results for `$nearSphere` compared with `$near` because with spherical geometry operators (i.e. `$nearSphere`), you also need to convert the any distances used in the query (i.e. `$maxDistance`) to radians in order to get the right result. Here, it doesn't look like you converted `$maxDistance` to radians.

To convert from distance to radians, divide the distance by the radius of the earth. If you are using metric units, this would be  6378.137 km. If you are using imperial units, this would be: 3963.192 mi

Try the `$nearSphere` query again with `$maxDistance` converted to radians.

Comment: Wait a minute. So we specify longitude and latitude in DEGREE and then specify the $maxDistance in radiant? Are you sure? Where can I see it? I am using degree as $maxDistance. Where in the documentation it says that it should be in radian? Also my result is off by 2, not by 180/pi

Comment: "All distances use radians. This allows you to easily multiply by the radius of the earth (about 6371 km or 3959 miles) to get the distance in your choice of units. Conversely, divide by the radius of the earth when doing queries."
from: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing

Comment: Perfect. I upvoted your answer on the stackoverflow too.

Comment: I still don't get it. To convert 1 m to radians, I need to divide that meter by 6378.137 km? Why is it 1000 times off?